# React dynamic forms that are nested

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm **soooo** close to getting this to work but just can't seem to wrap my head around this.

I have a form that's supposed to submit to a json file with the following structure:

```
    {
      title: '',
      content: [
        {className: '', body: ''}
      ]
    }
```

I'm able to set the state for the title no problem, as well as the first object in the content array. I think I need to create a loop or something? Below is my full component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class AddEditPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      title: '',
      content: [
        {className: '', body: ''}
      ]
    }
    this.addInput = this.addInput.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleNestedChange = this.handleNestedChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    const value = e.target.value
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: value
    })
  }

  handleNestedChange(e) {
    const value = e.target.value
    console.log(e.target.id)
    this.setState({

    })

  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state)
  }

  addInput() {
    const newInput = { className: '', body: ''}
    this.setState({content: this.state.content.concat(newInput)});
  }


  render() {
    const contentInputs = this.state.content.map((content, i)=> {
     return (
        <div key={i}>
          <input 
            type="text" 
            name="className"
            id={`${i}`} 
            placeholder="Class name"
            onChange={this.handleNestedChange}
          />
          <input 
            type="text" 
            name="body" 
            placeholder="Body"
            id={`${i}`}
            onChange={this.handleNestedChange}
          />
        </div>
      )
    })

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>New Page</h2>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input 
            type="text" 
            name="title" 
            placeholder={this.state.title || `Enter the title`}
            onChange={this.handleChange} 
            />
          <h3>Content</h3>
            {contentInputs}
            <button onClick={this.addInput}>Add</button>
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AddEditPage;
```

& praise for the answer haha

Comment: What exactly is your issue?  One thing to note is the way you have addInput, state.content will never grow (I believe).  Try using push instead, ie, let newValues = this.state.content.push(newInput) then this.setState({ content: newValues });

Comment: @terpinmd adding the inputs work great. It's setting the state part for the nested inputs that im having issues with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's not a very robust solution, assuming the `input` 'name' attributes always match exactly to the object keys in your state, you can do this:

```
handleNestedChange(e) {
    const newStateContent = this.state.content;
    newStateContent[e.target.id][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      content: newStateContent
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `handleNestedChange` is not binded properly, because the context `this` is refering to map function not the component. You have to bind map function with current context.

```
const contentInputs = this.state.content.map((content, i)=> { 
    return ( 
    <div key={i}> <input type="text" name="className" id={`${i}`} placeholder="Class name" onChange={this.handleNestedChange} /> <input type="text" name="body" placeholder="Body" id={`${i}`} onChange={this.handleNestedChange} /> </div> 
) 
}).bind(this)
```